# Best way to get datetime and daily availability in a news chatbot?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, conversational-interface, chatbots

I have a chatbot in which user receives news. I need to have some of the features below in my bot

1. Select a list of websites with a checkbox from where they receive news. Ex cnn.com
2. Specify one or more times when they receive news Ex 8:30 pm, 5 am
3. Specify the days of the week for each time slot. For example 8:30 pm and let the user select Monday to Friday and uncheck Saturdays and Sundays
4. Ability to add custom sites from where the user would like to receive news Ex: abcmynews.com

Though i ll be doing an app version of this, for the bot version, things are getting pretty tricky for me with respect to UX as this is new territory.

I am planning to use Messenger Webviews to achieve this functionality and I can right away think of putting 1 and 4 in a single webview screen on the chatbot

I have figured out the part where I can show a few news websites and let the people add more. It will be quite similar to this shopping list screen. While the UI below doesnt cover the ability to remove existing news sites, I would like to do that as well.

[image]

I am trying to figure out how I can take the time slot inputs and availability for each time slot. I came up with one idea for this but it doesnt look optimal

**Bot:** What time are you available?

**User:** 4 30 pm and 8 30 pm

**Bot:** Which days for 4 30 pm

**User:** All

**Bot:** Which days for 8 30 pm

**User:** All

That UX doesnt look quite right in my opinion. Should I add another screen in my webview? Should I come up with some other conversation style? Not sure what sort of date picker exists for this scenario inside the webview. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Doodle](https://doodle.com) is a simple scheduling tool for finding the best date for an event. You create a simple poll with dates (and optionally times) and the users with a link can vote which date(s) suit them best.

When creating a poll the flow is like this, which I find quite intuitive:

1) Initial screen
[image]

2) Select dates from calendar (in your case you don't need a calendar, you simply need options Monday - Sunday)
[image]

3) Click on Add times. The user is shown this:
[image]

If you don't need different times for each date this is where it ends. If you need to add different times for each day, you can do so by clicking on the button below the input field.

4) Enter different times for each day.

[image]

I really like their intuitive design and easy-to-understand language. Bonus points for displaying the timezone and having the possibility to add multiple times for one day.